# Perf on a code using exp function from Math.h shows time spent in resolving conflicts e_exp,w_exp

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, perf, math.h

my code computes in a loop exp of a large data array and when I tried to do Perf to profile the code, I get to see

Symbols conflicting in multiple files
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/math/../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_exp.c
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/math/../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/w_exp.c

I am using C++ and included "math.h", and a flag to specify std=c++11.
I am not sure why this conflict happens!

A simple snippet to generate this issue is to compile the below(release config) and run perf..

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <math.h>

    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {

      double d = 0;
      double e = 0;
      for (int i=0;i<8192;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<=255;j++)
        {
         e = ((j/255)-0.5)*((j/255)-0.5);
         e = exp(e);
         d = d + e;
        }
      cout<<d;

      return 0; 
    }
```

I am using eclipse to run profiling with perf and the messages are seen in Perf profile view.

Please help, it appears that the conflicts change with the magnitude of the value that goes into exp..Thank you.

Adding more information after exchanging some chat with Alfred
If we are using commandline instead of eclipse, then with `perf report`, two calls to exp can be seen
1. ieee754_exp_sse2
2. __GI__exp
These two are shown as conflicts in the eclipse GUI with an error marked on these lines

Comment: The code works fine here: `perf stat ./exp` - gives the expected output - i.e. just the result of the computation, and some performance numbers (where `exp` is your code)

Comment: Alfred,code works fine for me too, but in the "Perf profile view" where the time spent is analyzed, I see that a large percentage is spent in resolving conflicts libm-2.19.so

Comment: Is this in eclipse? You might provide some more details int the post.

Comment: Yes,I am using eclipse right now, but the perf.data can also be generated with `perf record ./exp`

Comment: Sorry- can't reproduce the error. With `sudo perf record ./exp` and then `sudo perf report` I'm getting profiling info just as expected - some lib calls, some kernel calls, but nothing like in OP.

Comment: @ Alfred, I am not sure how to open the same data that I see in eclipse window from command line..I agree that I don't see the same content when using `sudo perf report` and viewing perf.data within eclipse.